# Trying to show a function has period $\pi$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)  = e^{\cos x} \cos( \sin x ) $. I have been told that $f(x)$ has period $\pi$. But,

$$f(x + \pi ) = e^{\cos(x + \pi)} \cos( \sin(x + \pi ) ) = e^{- \cos x} \cos ( - \sin x ) \neq f(x)$$

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ does not have period $\pi$, but $2\pi$ instead.[image]

Answer (score 4):

$2\pi$ is clearly a period, but not $\pi$. For instance, $f(0) = e^1\cos 0 = e$, but $f(\pi) = e^{-1} \cos 0 = \frac{1}{e}$.

You are not missing anything.

Comment: On a side note, another property (easy to show) of $f$ is that it is even.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is the real part of $\exp\left(e^{ix}\right)$, hence its period is $2\pi$.